# VBA code to delete filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, macros, autofilter

I have the below code that will filter and delete the rows.
But my concern, its throwing a prompt with ok/cancel option. 
When I press "ok" it will delete the rows. But, I dont need a prompt.

```
Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*jpn*" _
            , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*promo*"
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete
```

Please help me in modifying code.Basically, I have filter it for data that contains jpn or promo and delete the entire rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check to ensure that there are visible rows to delete before attempting to remove them.

```
With ActiveSheet
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*jpn*", _
                    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*promo*"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then _
                .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry one question. Code also deleting the headers on row 1. How do I avoid this?

Comment: My apologies; I didn't offset down off the header row. Corrected above.